# Imitating a conveyor belt in `TikZ`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two circles of radii `4` and `5` drawn in blue and line segments drawn in purple between them so that the endpoints of them are perpendicular to radii of them. To give the impression that this depiction represents a conveyor belt, I will add two `arc` commands drawn in purple and will reduce the radii of the circles from `5cm` and `4cm` to `5cm-0.2pt` and `4cm-0.2pt`. Why is the command for drawing the circle `2pt` less than `5cm` not being implemented? This is the command that was misinterpreted.

```
\draw[blue] (center_of_first_circle) circle ({5cm - 0.2pt});
```

In my code, I used the following command to render a diagram that I am looking to modify.

```
\draw[blue] (center_of_first_circle) circle (5);
```

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}




\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]

%The centers of a circle of radius 4 and a circle of radius 5 are at a distance of 16 from each other. Two line segments
%are to be drawn between them so that they are tangent to the circles. (It is a sketch of a conveyor belt.) The radii to
%the point of tangency of the same line segment are parallel to each other. The centers of the circles are located on the
%x-axis - the center of the circle of radius 5 is centered at the origin, and the center of the circle of radius 4 is
%centered at (16,0). If \theta is the measure of the angle between the x-axis and the two radii, the slope of
%the line segment is sin\theta/(16 - cos\theta). So, the slope of the radii is (cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta. The slope is
%also tan\theta.
%x = 5cos\theta.
%x^2 + ((cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta)^2*x^2 = 5^2.
%tan\theta=(cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta.
%This is a quartic equation in the variable x. The solution is 5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66)). The point of tangency on the circle
%of radius 5 is
%(5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66)), 5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)).
%
%
\path (0,0) coordinate (center_of_first_circle) (16,0) coordinate (center_of_second_circle);
%
%
%
\path let \n1={5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66))}, \n2={5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)} in coordinate (a_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) at (\n1,\n2);
\path let \n1={5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66))}, \n2={5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)} in coordinate (another_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) at (\n1,-\n2);
%
\path let \n1={2*sqrt(66)}, \n2={sqrt(64*sqrt(66)-504)} in coordinate (a_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle) at (\n1,\n2);
\path let \n1={2*sqrt(66)}, \n2={sqrt(64*sqrt(66)-504)} in coordinate (another_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle) at (\n1,-\n2);
%
%
\draw (a_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) -- (a_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle);
\draw (another_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) -- (another_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle);
%
%
%
\draw[blue] (center_of_first_circle) circle (5);
\draw[blue]  (center_of_second_circle) circle (4);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation for why your command does not work:

Your transformation (`x=.25cm,y=.25cm`) kills it. The transformation has no effect in numbers which have units, so `5cm-2pt` is still `5cm-2pt`, it is not scaled.

To prevent it, you will need to scale `5cm-2pt` yourself. In the following code I use `1.25cm-2pt` and a similar number for the smaller circle.

---

If I understand your question, you can achieve that with `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
%The centers of a circle of radius 4 and a circle of radius 5 are at a distance of 16 from each other. Two line segments
%are to be drawn between them so that they are tangent to the circles. (It is a sketch of a conveyor belt.) The radii to
%the point of tangency of the same line segment are parallel to each other. The centers of the circles are located on the
%x-axis - the center of the circle of radius 5 is centered at the origin, and the center of the circle of radius 4 is
%centered at (16,0). If \theta is the measure of the angle between the x-axis and the two radii, the slope of
%the line segment is sin\theta/(16 - cos\theta). So, the slope of the radii is (cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta. The slope is
%also tan\theta.
%x = 5cos\theta.
%x^2 + ((cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta)^2*x^2 = 5^2.
%tan\theta=(cos\theta - 16)/sin\theta.
%This is a quartic equation in the variable x. The solution is 5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66)). The point of tangency on the circle
%of radius 5 is
%(5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66)), 5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)).
%
%
\path (0,0) coordinate (center_of_first_circle) (16,0) coordinate (center_of_second_circle);
%
\path let \n1={5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66))}, \n2={5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)} in coordinate (a_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) at (\n1,\n2);
\path let \n1={5*sqrt(65/2 - 4*sqrt(66))}, \n2={5*sqrt(4*sqrt(66) - 63/2)} in coordinate (another_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) at (\n1,-\n2);
%
\path let \n1={2*sqrt(66)}, \n2={sqrt(64*sqrt(66)-504)} in coordinate (a_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle) at (\n1,\n2);
\path let \n1={2*sqrt(66)}, \n2={sqrt(64*sqrt(66)-504)} in coordinate (another_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle) at (\n1,-\n2);
%
\draw[violet] (a_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) -- (a_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle);
\draw[violet] (another_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle) -- (another_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle);
%
\draw[blue] (center_of_first_circle) circle (1.25cm-2pt);
\draw[blue]  (center_of_second_circle) circle (1cm-2pt);

\tkzDrawArc[color=violet](center_of_first_circle,a_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle)(another_point_of_tangency_on_bigger_circle)
\tkzDrawArc[color=violet](center_of_second_circle,another_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle)(a_point_of_tangency_on_smaller_circle)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Btw you should never name your coordinates with such looooooong names... typing the names takes me considerable time :)

Comment: I want to keep this in `TikZ`.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire It is still Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Why is `TikZ` misinterpreting the command I issued?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Can you tell me what that command is? Both circle commands are not the commands which are "ignored"

Comment: `\draw[blue] (center_of_first_circle) circle ({5cm - 0.2pt});`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to state the command that was being misinterpreted. I have edited my post.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I added an explanation. Shortly: the transformation kills it.

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\pspicture[linewidth=1.2pt](15,8)
    \pnodes{P}(4,4)(11,4)
    \psCircleTangents(P0){3.2}(P1){2.7}
    \psset{linecolor=magenta}
    \psarc[origin=P0](P0){3.2}{(CircleTO2)}{(CircleTO4)}
    \psarc[origin=P1](P1){2.7}{(CircleTO3)}{(CircleTO1)}
    \psline(CircleTO2)(CircleTO1)
    \psline(CircleTO4)(CircleTO3)
    \psset{linecolor=blue}  
    \pscircle(P0){3}
    \pscircle(P1){2.5}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

## Unrealistic animation

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\multido{\r=0.1+0.1}{29}{
\pspicture[linewidth=1.2pt](15,8)
    \pnodes{P}(4,4)(11,4)
    \psCircleTangents(P0){3.2}(P1){\pscalculate{\r+0.2}}
    \psset{linecolor=magenta}
    \psarc[origin=P0](P0){3.2}{(CircleTO2)}{(CircleTO4)}
    \psarc[origin=P1](P1){!\r\space 0.2 add}{(CircleTO3)}{(CircleTO1)}
    \psline(CircleTO2)(CircleTO1)
    \psline(CircleTO4)(CircleTO3)
    \psset{linecolor=blue}  
    \pscircle(P0){3}
    \pscircle(P1){\r}
\endpspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be _very_ nice to see some animations!

Comment: Why do we need _\space_ following by _\r_ ?

Comment: @TrongVuong:  Without `\space` any characters that follows will be eaten. :-)

Comment: By "animation" I mean it is something like the rotation of a chain wheel in a bicycle. Hope to see it soon!

Answer (score 2):

With the style from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464143/121799). Earlier TI*k*Z only solutions can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7209/121799).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent of circles/.style args={%
at #1 and #2 with radii #3 and #4}{insert path={%
let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)*1pt/1cm},
    \n3={atan2(#4-#3,\n2)}
     in ($(#1)+(\n3+\n1+90:#3)$) -- ($(#2)+(\n3+\n1+90:#4)$)}}]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\offscale}{1.04}
 %
 \draw[blue] (0,0) coordinate (c1)  circle[radius=1.25cm]
   (4,0) coordinate (c2)  circle[radius=1cm];
 \draw[red,tangent of circles={at c1 and c2 with radii \offscale*1.25 and \offscale*1}]
 coordinate[pos=0] (tl) coordinate[pos=1] (tr)
 [tangent of circles={at c2 and c1 with radii \offscale*1 and \offscale*1.25}]
 coordinate[pos=0] (br) coordinate[pos=1] (bl);
 \draw[red] let \p1=($(tl)-(c1)$),\p2=($(bl)-(c1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
 in (tl) arc(\n1:\n2+360:\offscale*1.25);
 \draw[red] let \p1=($(tr)-(c2)$),\p2=($(br)-(c2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
 in (tr) arc(\n1:\n2:\offscale*1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{tangent of circles/.style args={%
at #1 and #2 with radii #3 and #4}{insert path={%
let \p1=($(#2)-(#1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)*1pt/1cm},
    \n3={atan2(#4-#3,\n2)}
     in ($(#1)+(\n3+\n1+90:#3)$) -- ($(#2)+(\n3+\n1+90:#4)$)}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1.25,1.2,...,0.25,0.3,0.35,...,1.2}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rOne}{1.25}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rTwo}{\X}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rPlus}{0.05}
 %
 \path[use as bounding box] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (5.5,1.5);
 \draw[blue] (0,0) coordinate (c1)  circle[radius=\rOne*1cm]
   (4,0) coordinate (c2)  circle[radius=\rTwo*1cm];
 \draw[red,tangent of circles={at c1 and c2 with radii {\rOne+\rPlus} and {\rTwo+\rPlus}}]
 coordinate[pos=0] (tl) coordinate[pos=1] (tr)
 [tangent of circles={at c2 and c1 with radii {\rTwo+\rPlus} and {\rOne+\rPlus}}]
 coordinate[pos=0] (br) coordinate[pos=1] (bl);
 \draw[red] let \p1=($(tl)-(c1)$),\p2=($(bl)-(c1)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
 in (tl) arc(\n1:\n2+360:\rOne+\rPlus);
 \draw[red] let \p1=($(tr)-(c2)$),\p2=($(br)-(c2)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
 in (tr) arc(\n1:\n2:\rTwo+\rPlus);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a little fun, would you please add an animation which looks like a rotating chain wheel of a bicycle? :)

Comment: @JouleV Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458120/121799 ?

Comment: Yes! (of course with the addition of the two wheels)

Comment: @JouleV You can ask a question for that...

Comment: Or maybe like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254073).

Comment: @marmot Ah, it is not that important - it is just a suggestion * for fun *

Comment: @MarkWibrow Yes, I like and upvoted your answer long ago. (Can you combine the links and the animation?)